# one react component updates all the other react components

Tags: reactjs, react-table

I have a react table and one of the columns of it is another component. This component is a dropdown which get its value with an API call which I have defined in componentDidMount().

I have use case where in if user selects any value from the dropdown, I want to save that field to the DB. So I defined this post call in the `handleChange` function of the dropdown.

Issue is that when I change the value in any one row, every other component in other rows also calls the makes the network calls which is defined in componentDidMount(). So componentDidMount() is called for all the 4 entries. I confirmed on the server side as well. I can see four get requests(I have only 4 rows for now). I am thoroughly confused why it's behaving this way?

Parent Component

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactTable from 'react-table';
import 'react-table/react-table.css';
import Popup from "reactjs-popup";

export default class DetailsTable extends React.Component {

  constructor(props, context) {
    super(props, context);

    this.state = {
      shipmentDataMap : { },
      selectedRow: null,
      downloadableAlerts: []
    };
    this.setState = this.setState.bind(this);
    this.handleRowClick = this.handleRowClick.bind(this);
    this.handleReassignment = this.handleReassignment.bind(this);
    this.handleStatusUpdate = this.handleStatusUpdate.bind(this);
    this.generateFilteredArr = this.generateFilteredArr.bind(this);
    this.handleDownload = this.handleDownload.bind(this);
    this.updateActualEntity = this.updateActualEntity.bind(this);
  };


 componentDidMount() {
         axios.post('/entity/getRoute', {
           trackingId: this.state.tid
         })
         .then((response) => {
           let tempRoute = [];
           response.data.route.forEach(element => {
             tempRoute.push({ label: element['node'], value: element['node'] });
           })
           this.setState({route: tempRoute});
         })
         .catch(function (error) {
           console.log(error);
         });
       };

    updateActualEntity = (trackingId, updatedEntity) => {
    let updatedRecord = this.state.shipmentDataMap[trackingId];
    updatedRecord.actualEntity = updatedEntity;
    this.setState({shipmentDataMap: this.state.shipmentDataMap});
  };

render() {
    const TableColumns = [{
        Header: 'Actions',
        id: 'actionPopupButton',
        filterable: false,
        style: {'textAlign': 'left'},
        Cell: row => (<div><ReassignPopup data={row.original} updateRowFunc={this.handleReassignment} nodeOptions={this.props.nodeOptions}/> 
                        <br/>
                        <UpdateStatusPopup data={row.original} updateRowFunc={this.handleStatusUpdate} statusOptions={this.props.statusOptions}/>
                        </div>)
      },
      {
        Header: 'Assigned Node',
        headerStyle: {'whiteSpace': 'unset'},
        accessor: 'node',
        style: {'whiteSpace': 'unset'}
      }, {
        Header: 'TID',
        headerStyle: {'whiteSpace': 'unset'},
        accessor: 'tid',
        width: 140,
        filterMethod: (filter, row) => {
                    return row[filter.id].startsWith(filter.value)
                  },
        Cell: props => <a href={`https://eagleeye-eu.amazon.com/search?type=Scannable&display=leg&value=${props.value}`} target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer">{props.value}</a>
      },
      {
        Header: 'Predicted Entity',
        headerStyle: {'whiteSpace': 'unset'},
        filterable: false,
        accessor: 'predictedEntity',
        style: {'whiteSpace': 'unset'},
      },
      {
        Header: 'Feedback',
        headerStyle: {'whiteSpace': 'unset'},
        filterable: false,
        accessor: 'actualEntity',
        width: 140,
        style: {'whiteSpace': 'unset', overflow: 'visible'},
        Cell: row => (<div><AbusiveEntityComponent entity={row.original.actualEntity}
                  tid={row.original.tid} trackingDetailsId={row.original.trackingDetailsId}
                  updateActualEntityInShipmentData={this.updateActualEntity}/></div>)
      }

      return <div> 
    <CSVLink data={this.state.downloadableAlerts} filename="ShipmentAlerts.csv" className="hidden" ref={(r) => this.csvLink = r} target="_blank"/>
    <ReactTable
      ref={(r)=>this.reactTable=r}
      className='-striped -highlight'
      filterable
      data={Object.values(this.state.shipmentDataMap)}
      //resolveData={data => data.map(row => row)}
      columns={TableColumns}
      //filtered={this.state.filtered}
      filtered={this.generateFilteredArr(this.props.filterMap, this.props.searchParams)}
      /*onFilteredChange={(filtered, column, value) => {
        this.onFilteredChangeCustom(value, column.id || column.accessor);
      }}*/
      defaultFilterMethod={(filter, row, column) => {
            const id = filter.pivotId || filter.id;
            if (typeof filter.value === "object") {
              return row[id] !== undefined
                ? filter.value.indexOf(row[id].toString()) > -1
                : true;
            } else {
              return row[id] !== undefined
                ? String(row[id]).indexOf(filter.value) > -1
                : true;
            }
          }}

      defaultPageSize={10}
      //pageSize={10}
      previousText='Previous Page'
      nextText='Next Page'
      noDataText='No intervention alerts found'
      style={{
            fontSize: "12px",
            height: "67.4vh" // Using fixed pixels/limited height will force the table body to overflow and scroll
          }}
      getTheadFilterProps={() => {return {style: {display: "none" }}}}
      getTbodyProps={() => {return {style: {overflowX: "hidden" }}}} //For preventing extra scrollbar in Firefox/Safari
      /*
      getTrProps={(state, rowInfo) => {
        if (rowInfo && rowInfo.row) {
          return {
            onClick: (e) => {this.handleRowClick(e, rowInfo)},
            style: {
                  //background: rowInfo.index === this.state.selectedRow ? '#00afec' : 'white',
                  color: rowInfo.index === this.state.selectedRow ? 'blue' : 'black'
                }    
          }
        } else {
          return {}
        }
      }
    } */
      />
  </div>;
  }
}
```

Child Component

```
import React from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';

export default class AbusiveEntityComponent extends React.Component {
  constructor(props, context) {
    super(props, context);
    this.state = {
        entity: this.props.entity,
      tid: this.props.tid,
      trackingDetailsId: this.props.trackingDetailsId,
      route: []
    };

    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
  }

  handleChange = (event) => {
    var selected = event.target.value;
    if(selected !== '' && this.state.entity !== selected) {
      if (window.confirm('Are you sure you want to select: '+ selected)) {
        axios.post('/entity/upateAbusiveEntity', {
        trackingDetailsId: this.state.trackingDetailsId,
        abusiveEntity: selected
      }).then( (response) =>{
        this.setState({entity: selected});
        this.props.updateActualEntityInShipmentData(this.state.tid, selected);
      })
      .catch(function (error) {
        console.log(error);
      });
      }
    }
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    console.log("did mount");
    axios.get('/entity/getRoute', {
      params: {
        trackingId: this.state.tid
      }
    })
    .then((response) => {
      let tempRoute = [];
      let prev="";
      response.data.route.forEach(element => {
        if(prev!== "") {
          tempRoute.push(prev+"-"+element['node'])
        }
        tempRoute.push(element['node']);
        prev=element['node'];
      })
      this.setState({route: [''].concat(tempRoute)});
    })
    .catch(function (error) {
      console.log(error);
    });
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="AbusiveEntityDiv">
         <select onChange={this.handleChange} value={this.state.entity===null?'':this.state.entity} 
            style={{width: 100}}>
          { this.state.route.map(value => <option key={value} value={value}>{value}</option>) }
         </select>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

My question is if componentDidUpdate() is not the correct place to fetch data for dropdown, where should I define the network call ?

Comment: Please provide a complete example, especially the code of the parent component.

Comment: @ford04, is the update okay or you need more information?

Comment: Just saw from your code update that it's mainly a `react-table` issue. Honestly, I am not so familiar with that package. You say, that `componentDidMount` is invoked for each  renderer component (`Cell`) again after an update, so they are obviously unmounted and recreated by `react-table`. I [modified](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-table-cell-renderers-fbtg6) one of their samples, but could not reproduce your issue. Maybe you provide a simple codesandbox so it's more likely that somebody can help?

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution. In the parent component I maintain a state of shipmentstatusmap. One of the columns of this map is acutalEntity. Now in the child component, whenever user selects the value from dropdown, I callback the parent to update the shipmentStatusMap as well. This callback was my problem.

Because now the state of parent component changes, it unmount the child and re-mount it. So it's componentDidMount is called for all the rows which in turn makes the API call.

**Solution**

Since I want the dropdown values only once when whole parent component is loaded, I can either move the API to constructor or the in the componentDidMount() of parent. Fetching data in constructor is not a good idea .

So I moved this API call in parent and voila! everything works as expected.

updated code:

Child component

```
import React from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';

export default class AbusiveEntityComponent extends React.Component {
  constructor(props, context) {
    super(props, context);
    this.state = {
        entity: this.props.entity,
      tid: this.props.tid,
      trackingDetailsId: this.props.trackingDetailsId,
      route: this.props.route
    };

    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
  }

  handleChange = (event) => {
    var selected = event.target.value;
    if(selected !== '' && this.state.entity !== selected) {
      if (window.confirm('Are you sure you want to select: '+ selected)) {
        axios.post('/entity/upateAbusiveEntity', {
        trackingDetailsId: this.state.trackingDetailsId,
        abusiveEntity: selected
      }).then( (response) =>{
        this.setState({entity: selected});
        this.props.updateActualEntityInShipmentData(this.state.tid, selected);
      })
      .catch(function (error) {
        console.log(error);
      });
      }
    }
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="AbusiveEntityDiv">
         <select onChange={this.handleChange} value={this.state.entity===null?'':this.state.entity} 
            style={{width: 100}}>
          { this.state.route.map(value => <option key={value} value={value}>{value}</option>) }
         </select>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Parent component

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactTable from 'react-table';
import 'react-table/react-table.css';
import Popup from "reactjs-popup";

export default class DetailsTable extends React.Component {

  constructor(props, context) {
    super(props, context);

    this.state = {
      shipmentDataMap : { },
      selectedRow: null,
      downloadableAlerts: []
    };
    this.setState = this.setState.bind(this);
    this.handleRowClick = this.handleRowClick.bind(this);
    this.handleReassignment = this.handleReassignment.bind(this);
    this.handleStatusUpdate = this.handleStatusUpdate.bind(this);
    this.generateFilteredArr = this.generateFilteredArr.bind(this);
    this.handleDownload = this.handleDownload.bind(this);
    this.updateActualEntity = this.updateActualEntity.bind(this);
  };


// this portion was updated
  componentDidMount() {
    fetch('/shipment/all')
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(shipmentList => {
        var tidToShipmentMap = {};
        var totalShipmentCount = shipmentList.length;
        var loadedShipmentRoute = 0;
        shipmentList.forEach(shipment => {

          axios.get('/entity/getRoute', {
            params: {
              trackingId: shipment.tid
            }
          })
          .then(response => {
            let tempRoute = [];
            let prev="";
            response.data.route.forEach(element => {
              if(prev!== "") {
                tempRoute.push(prev+"-"+element['node'])
              }
              tempRoute.push(element['node']);
              prev=element['node'];
            })

            shipment.route = [''].concat(tempRoute);
            tidToShipmentMap[shipment.tid] = shipment;
            loadedShipmentRoute++;
            if (loadedShipmentRoute === totalShipmentCount) {
              this.setState({ shipmentDataMap: tidToShipmentMap});
              console.log(tidToShipmentMap);
            }
          })
          .catch(function (error) {
            console.log(error);
          });
        });
      })
      .catch(error => console.log(error));
  };

    updateActualEntity = (trackingId, updatedEntity) => {
    let updatedRecord = this.state.shipmentDataMap[trackingId];
    updatedRecord.actualEntity = updatedEntity;
    this.setState({shipmentDataMap: this.state.shipmentDataMap});
  };

render() {
    const TableColumns = [{
        Header: 'Actions',
        id: 'actionPopupButton',
        filterable: false,
        style: {'textAlign': 'left'},
        Cell: row => (<div><ReassignPopup data={row.original} updateRowFunc={this.handleReassignment} nodeOptions={this.props.nodeOptions}/> 
                        <br/>
                        <UpdateStatusPopup data={row.original} updateRowFunc={this.handleStatusUpdate} statusOptions={this.props.statusOptions}/>
                        </div>)
      },
      {
        Header: 'Assigned Node',
        headerStyle: {'whiteSpace': 'unset'},
        accessor: 'node',
        style: {'whiteSpace': 'unset'}
      }, {
        Header: 'TID',
        headerStyle: {'whiteSpace': 'unset'},
        accessor: 'tid',
        width: 140,
        filterMethod: (filter, row) => {
                    return row[filter.id].startsWith(filter.value)
                  },
        Cell: props => <a href={`https://eagleeye-eu.amazon.com/search?type=Scannable&display=leg&value=${props.value}`} target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer">{props.value}</a>
      },
      {
        Header: 'Predicted Entity',
        headerStyle: {'whiteSpace': 'unset'},
        filterable: false,
        accessor: 'predictedEntity',
        style: {'whiteSpace': 'unset'},
      },
      {
        Header: 'Feedback',
        headerStyle: {'whiteSpace': 'unset'},
        filterable: false,
        accessor: 'actualEntity',
        width: 140,
        style: {'whiteSpace': 'unset', overflow: 'visible'},
        Cell: row => (<div><AbusiveEntityComponent entity={row.original.actualEntity}
                  tid={row.original.tid} trackingDetailsId={row.original.trackingDetailsId}
                  updateActualEntityInShipmentData={this.updateActualEntity}/></div>)
      }

      return <div> 
    <CSVLink data={this.state.downloadableAlerts} filename="ShipmentAlerts.csv" className="hidden" ref={(r) => this.csvLink = r} target="_blank"/>
    <ReactTable
      ref={(r)=>this.reactTable=r}
      className='-striped -highlight'
      filterable
      data={Object.values(this.state.shipmentDataMap)}
      //resolveData={data => data.map(row => row)}
      columns={TableColumns}
      //filtered={this.state.filtered}
      filtered={this.generateFilteredArr(this.props.filterMap, this.props.searchParams)}
      /*onFilteredChange={(filtered, column, value) => {
        this.onFilteredChangeCustom(value, column.id || column.accessor);
      }}*/
      defaultFilterMethod={(filter, row, column) => {
            const id = filter.pivotId || filter.id;
            if (typeof filter.value === "object") {
              return row[id] !== undefined
                ? filter.value.indexOf(row[id].toString()) > -1
                : true;
            } else {
              return row[id] !== undefined
                ? String(row[id]).indexOf(filter.value) > -1
                : true;
            }
          }}

      defaultPageSize={10}
      //pageSize={10}
      previousText='Previous Page'
      nextText='Next Page'
      noDataText='No intervention alerts found'
      style={{
            fontSize: "12px",
            height: "67.4vh" // Using fixed pixels/limited height will force the table body to overflow and scroll
          }}
      getTheadFilterProps={() => {return {style: {display: "none" }}}}
      getTbodyProps={() => {return {style: {overflowX: "hidden" }}}} //For preventing extra scrollbar in Firefox/Safari
      /*
      getTrProps={(state, rowInfo) => {
        if (rowInfo && rowInfo.row) {
          return {
            onClick: (e) => {this.handleRowClick(e, rowInfo)},
            style: {
                  //background: rowInfo.index === this.state.selectedRow ? '#00afec' : 'white',
                  color: rowInfo.index === this.state.selectedRow ? 'blue' : 'black'
                }    
          }
        } else {
          return {}
        }
      }
    } */
      />
  </div>;
  }
}
```